# R, conditional replacement using row and column names and values from another table

Tags: r

I have two data frames. The first contains the number of occurrences of specific sequences (rows) in different samples (columns), and looks like this:

```
df1<- as.data.frame(matrix(c(9, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 2472, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 310, 0, 2460, 0, 0, 0, 10), nrow=8, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE))

names(df1)<-c("A","B","C")

rownames(df1)<-paste("seq00",seq(1:8),sep="")
```

The second contains the ids of rows and columns that need to be updated in the first table, along with the value change. It looks like this:

```
df2<-as.data.frame(matrix(cbind(c("A","A","A","B","C","A","B","C"),c("seq001","seq002", "seq003" ,"seq007" ,"seq008" ,"seq004" ,"seq005", "seq006"),list( -9  ,-9  ,-9 , 11, -10,  27, -11,  10)),nrow=8, ncol=3, byrow=F))

names(df2)<-c("colIDs","rowIDs","change.value.by")
```

Is there an easy way to update the values in the first data frame by using the row and column ids from the second table? My actual data frames are quite large, and not all of the values in df1 will need to be updated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` and `tidyr`. This works by `gather`ing our data into long format, using a `left_join` to merge on the desired changes, `mutate`ing the changes on, then `spread`ing back into wide format:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% add_rownames("row") %>%
        gather(var, val, -row) %>%
        left_join(df2, by = c(row = "rowIDs", var = "colIDs")) %>%
        mutate(val = ifelse(is.na(change.value.by), val, val + change.value.by)) %>%
        select(-change.value.by) %>%
        spread(var, val)

Source: local data frame [8 x 4]

     row     A     B     C
   (chr) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1 seq001     0     0     0
2 seq002     0     0     0
3 seq003     0     0     0
4 seq004  2499     0     0
5 seq005     0   -11     0
6 seq006     0     0   320
7 seq007     0  2471     0
8 seq008     0     0     0
```

Comment: thank you! this worked perfectly once I fixed my original code so the last column in df2 contained numbers instead of a list!

Comment: nice one - I forgot to include it: `df2[] <- lapply(df2, unlist)`